# Need to make a join use column data as wild card for common match

Tags: sql, database, psql

Hey guys I am trying to use data from one table that contains just URLS to see if there is any varation or use of them URLS in my main table

```
                  url                                                                                               │··························································································
---------------------------------------                                                                             │··························································································
 .0.9.40.52                                                                                                         │··························································································
 .00000000314.0000000265.00000225.0323                                                                              │··························································································
 .001916.com                                                                                                        │··························································································
 .00386.com                                                                                                         │··························································································
 .00-5dj-ar4c.club                                                                                                  │··························································································
 .007band.ru                                                                                                        │··························································································
 .007crconcert-japan.com                                                                                            │··························································································
 .007pi.com                                                                                                         │··························································································
 .00dt7myo.work                                                                                                     │··························································································
 .00dzhqbghr.com                                                                                                    │··························································································
(10 rows)
```

Main Table

```
 user_id | campaign_id |                                                                                                          url
                                |      send_time
---------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------+---------------------
 8468677 |     1004001 | http://twitter.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fatwonline.com%2Faircraft-orders-deliveries%2Fnigeria-s-arik-air-replaces-boeing-747s-787s&text=Nigeria%E2%80%99s+Arik+Air+replaces+Boeing+74
7s+with+787s&count=none         | 2017-01-28 13:01:28
 8468677 |     1003945 | http://twitter.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fatwonline.com%2Fairframes%2Fairbaltic-cs300-performance-exceeding-expectations&text=AirBaltic%3A+CS300+performance+%E2%80%98exceeding+expect
ations%E2%80%99&count=none      | 2017-01-14 13:03:29
 8468677 |     1004189 | http://twitter.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fatwonline.com%2Fairframes%2Famerican-again-defers-a350-deliveries-first-pushed-back-2020&text=American+again+defers+A350+deliveries%3B+first
+pushed+back+to+2020&count=none | 2017-05-02 12:02:04
 8468677 |     1004057 | http://twitter.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fatwonline.com%2Fairframes%2Fatlas-has-acquired-all-20-767s-be-operated-amazon&text=Atlas+has+acquired+all+20+767s+to+be+operated+for+Amazon&
count=none                      | 2017-02-28 13:02:13
(4 rows)
```

I was trying to run the following

```
select t1.user_id,t1.campaign_id,t1.url
from madison_alldb as t1
inner join madison_url as t2
ON t1.url LIKE CONCAT('%',t1.url, '%');
```

But when I go back to my tmux it just says Killed.. I also am not sure if the above will work.

My goal is to have only a limit of users that have a domain that is a wildcard match from my URL table.

Comment: limit works.. but that wasn't suppose to apart of the above.. I had a limit just to test the previous query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of query is very hard to optimize.  One minor optimization is to use `exists` rather than a `join`:

```
select ma.*
from madison_alldb ma
where exists (select 1
              from madison_url mu
              where ma.url like concat('%', mu.url, '%')
             )
limit 10;
```

However, this still has to do a nested loop join. The only difference is fewer comparisons when there is a match.

Comment: giving that a shot and i removed the limit that was just for testing purposes.. the Killed statement show when I am not using the limit with the previous statement

Comment: Ran for three days and then had to be killed..the list of just urls is about 80k line and the list its checking it over 400k.. maybe just to much?